# Django: How to import CSS libraries in Ajax template

Tags: css, ajax, django, django-templates

I am using Ajax in my Django project to implement some simple searching. In my template folder, I have created an html file called "ajax_search.html" where I write how I want my objects to be displayed on a page. Right now it looks like this:

```
{% if puzzles.count > 0 %}
{% for puzzle in puzzles %}
<a href="{% url 'puzzle' puzzleID=puzzle.id %}">
{{puzzle.title}}
</a>
<br>
{% endfor %}
{% elif search_len < 3 %}

{% else %}
No puzzles match the search
{% endif %}
```

This works fine, but I wanted to style it to look better. Is there any way I could import some CSS into this template?

Thank you!

Comment: Can't you just add some classes to the markup you generate in `ajax_search.html` and style them in your global CSS?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "global CSS"? My ajax_search.html isn't extending my base.html, so I have no CSS files linked to it.

Comment: Why not just add a "css" template block in your base template that you can override or extend?

Comment: ohjuny - By global CSS I mean the CSS file that you use for the rest of your page, the page the ajax result is embedded on. When using ajax, the HTML is just inserted into the page, and the CSS won't care where the HTML comes from.